# Export ElasticSearch objects to CSV with Perl

Tags: perl, csv, elasticsearch

I need to export some objects from an ElasticSearch db in the form of CSV "tables".
I just need to retrieve all records from a specified index.
I've tried this found from clintongormley, but I'm facing inssues. The perl code is:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use ElasticSearch;
use Text::CSV_XS;

my $csv_file = 'output.csv';
open my $fh, '>:encoding(utf8)', $csv_file or die $!;


my $csv = Text::CSV_XS->new;
my $e = ElasticSearch->new(servers => '127.0.0.1:9200');
my $s = $e->scrolled_search(
    index => 'myindex',
    type => 'mytype',
    query => { match_all => '' }
);

my @field_names = qw(title name foo bar);

while (my $doc = $s->next) {
    my @cols = map {$doc->$_} @field_names;
    $csv->print($fh, \@cols);
}

close $fh or die $!;
```

I get the following:

```
[_na] query malformed, no field after start_object];
```

I think the problem is in the es query.

Any suggestions?

Comment: I solved the problem with the query, replacing "query => {match_all => ''}" with "query => {match_all => {}".

But now I'm facing a new problem: when the compiler start, I get the error: Can't call method title on unblessed reference etc.

The line is where "my @cols = map {$doc->.." is.

Comment: That means your `$doc` is not an object. Are you sure that it's not just a hashref and you need to go `$doc->{$_}`? I've not looked at the documentation though.

Comment: @simbabque Even better, it looks like it [returns an arrayref of hashrefs](https://metacpan.org/pod/ElasticSearch::ScrolledSearch#next).

Comment: It was my fault regarding perl syntax near "map" macro.
But yes, now it works, but the CSV is something like an array of hashrefs.. Shouldn't it return "real" values?
It's the first time I use that perl library, and it's quite odd that the CSV files created are practically useless.

Answer (score 0):

Mea culpa. I wrote that code very quickly without testing it :)

Also, the code is very old and refers to the now deprecated ElasticSearch.pm modulde.  The new module is [Elasticsearch.pm](https://metacpan.org/pod/Elasticsearch) (note the small `s`).

Here is the code rewritten to use the new module, and so it actually works:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use Elasticsearch;
use Elasticsearch::Scroll;
use Text::CSV_XS;

my $csv_file = 'output.csv';
open my $fh, '>:encoding(utf8)', $csv_file or die $!;

my $csv = Text::CSV_XS->new;
$csv->eol("\r\n");

my $es = Elasticsearch->new( nodes => '127.0.0.1:9200' );
my $s = Elasticsearch::Scroll->new(
    es    => $es,
    index => 'myindex',
    type  => 'mytype',
    body  => { query => { match_all => {} } }
);

my @field_names = qw(title count);

while ( my $doc = $s->next ) {
    my @cols = map { $doc->{_source}{$_} } @field_names;
    $csv->print( $fh, \@cols );

}

close $fh or die $!;
```

To test it, you can run these `curl` commands to setup an index with some data:

```
# delete the test index in case it already exists
curl -XDELETE localhost:9200/myindex

# create some sample docs
curl -XPOST localhost:9200/myindex/mytype/_bulk -d'
{"index": {}}
{"title": "Doc one", "count": 1}
{"index": {}}
{"title": "Doc two", "count": 2}
{"index": {}}
{"title": "Doc three", "count": 3}
'
```

If you then run the Perl code, the file `output.csv` will look like this:

```
"Doc two",2
"Doc three",3
"Doc one",1
```

Apologies for the bad original example code

Comment: Hi, thanks for new code.
I've tested it, but it unfortunately still doesn't work :(
If I try with your example code, I get a csv file with only a single comma, but without values.
Insted, if I edit the query, inserting the fields I want to return:

es    => $es,
    index => 'myindex',
    type  => 'mytype',
    fields => ['title', 'count'],
    body  => { query => { match_all => {} } }

I also get this error when executing:

Can't call method "search" on an undefined value at Elasticsearch/Scroll.pm line 17.

Any hint?

Comment: After posting this answer, I released a new version of Elasticsearch which broke the `$doc = $s->next` call!  I've just released a fixed version. Will take a little while to hit the CPAN servers but you can install it directly from here: http://cpan.metacpan.org/authors/id/D/DR/DRTECH/Elasticsearch-1.02.tar.gz